# TeamCity Perforce Error - No files to submit

Tags: version-control, teamcity, perforce

I run a compile configuration on TeamCity that submits the binaries at the end. It triggers after some specific submits but the binaries don't always end up different. So I run a revert for all unchanged files before trying to submit. What this means is that I commonly have TC trying to submit a changelist with 0 files.

This behavior is fine and harmless but p4 returns a code 1 when trying to submit an empty CL, which in turn caused the TC config to fail. I feel like there should be an easy way to resolve this but I can't find any docs or anyone asking the question before.

```
[Step 4/5] No files to submit.
[Step 4/5] Process exited with code 1
[Step 4/5] Step Submit changes (Command Line) failed
```

Any ideas would be tremendously helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There's noting you can do about the return value of the perforce submit if there are no files but from the TeamCity configuration perspective you stop it from failing by adding any other line after the submit, so that the last entry into the step isn't the exit code from the submit. Just writing:

```
p4 submit //...
echo
```

will result in the config completing successfully.